# How can i overcome "unsafe" error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unsafe, strcpy

I'm working on a project that is basically controlling a parking lot. And in some point of my code I use the function `strcpy()`, but I am getting an error saying that this function may be unsafe.
Here's the part of the code I'm using `strcpy()`:

```
Automovel::Automovel(char * matr, Data ent, double comp) {
    //CONSTRUTOR POR ENUMERAÇAO:
    //RECEBE A MATRICULA, A DATA DE ENTRADA E O COMPRIMENTO DO CARRO
    //POSIÇAO E VALOR PAGO FICA INDEFINIDO
    matricula = new char[11];
    entry = new Data(ent);

    strcpy(matricula, matr);
    comprimento = comp;
    pos[0] = -1; pos[1] = -1;
    pago = -1;
}
```

I need to use the function, so, how can I solve this error?

Comment: Well, that post didn't answer how can i solve it, still using the strcpy() function

Comment: It's not an error to use an unsafe function. I'm assuming your error is that `comprimento` was never declared.

Comment: @CésarPereira, it seems to me that you could use the safe `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Comment: If there is an `unsafe warning` follow [these steps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873048/getting-an-error-fopen-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-when-complin).

Comment: @zneak i already tried to use strncpy() and it gives the same error

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to need a person who can read ~~Spanish~~Portuguese then.

Comment: @EliSadoff thanks, that did it. If you want post it on an answer and i will aprove you to give you reputation

Comment: @zneak portuguese actually xD but that are all variables, so no matter the language xD

Comment: I think this might work - Place the following right below your `#include<>` lines: `#define   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `strcpy` is an 'unsafe' function so you need to disable the `unsafe warning` in Visual Studio so follow [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21873048/getting-an-error-fopen-this-function-or-variable-may-be-unsafe-when-complin).

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say, but I'll assume you're using Visual Studio; that's where I've encountered the error.

Either bite the bullet and use `strcpy_s` etc., or do this:

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

This disables the "feature" that makes `strcpy` an error.

Comment: And i should do this in every file i get the error? I have many .cpp files in my project

Comment: I would.  But you can also do this through the IDE.  Go to Project Properties, C/C++, Advanced, then Disable Specific Warnings.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx